# How to send messages into MSK topic from a Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-msk

currently I have a MSK cluster defined in terraform:

```
resource "aws_msk_cluster" "this" {

  cluster_name           = local.cluster_name
  kafka_version          = var.kafka_version # 2.8.2.tiered
  number_of_broker_nodes = var.number_of_broker_nodes
  enhanced_monitoring    = var.enhanced_monitoring
  storage_mode           = var.cluster_storage_mode
  tags                   = var.tags


  broker_node_group_info {
    client_subnets  = var.broker_node_client_subnets
    instance_type   = var.broker_node_instance_type
    security_groups = var.security_groups_id
  }
}
```

And I would like to create a Lambda function that writes some data into a MSK cluster topic. I understand that I need to create the lambda within the same subnet as the cluster, but I do not find examples or information on how to actually send a message from a Lambda.

I have the lambda as follows:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "write_to_msk" {
  for_each = var.kafka_topics

  filename         = ...
  function_name    = ...
  role             = ... # Role with 
"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole",
"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute", 
"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"

  handler          = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = ...
  runtime          = "python3.8"

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids          = var.subnets
    security_group_ids  = var.sg
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      kafka_topic = var.kafka_topics[each.key]
    }
  }
}
```

And in the python script I receive what I need to write from an event:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    logger.info(f"[lambda_function] Received event: {json.dumps(event)}")
    return {
        'message' : 'Completed'
    }
```

Comment: Well, you need a Python library for that I think. Take a look here: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-kafka-with-python-54dc20717cf7.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic implementation of it using fire and forget strategy.

```py
import json
import time
from time import time
from confluent_kafka import Producer

producer = Producer({
    'bootstrap.servers': process.env.KAFKA_BROKER,
    'socket.timeout.ms': 100,
    'api.version.request': 'false',
    'broker.version.fallback': '0.9.0',
    'message.max.bytes': 1000000000
})


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = {"name": "xyz", "email": "xyz@"}

    send_msg_async(data)

    return { 
        'isHandled' : true
    }

def send_msg_async(msg):
    print("Sending message")
    try:
        msg_json_str = str({"data": json.dumps(msg)})
        producer.produce(
            process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC,
            msg_json_str
        )
        producer.flush()
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error : ", ex)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried, and I get the following error:

...: Disconnected: verify that security.protocol is correctly configured, broker might require SASL authentication (after 2ms in state UP)

The three dots, is the server that I have added, the process.env.KAFKA_BROKER variable, obtained after running:

aws kafka get-bootstrap-brokers --cluster-arn <arn>
{
    "BootstrapBrokerStringTls": "..." # 3 Strings ended in :9094
}